# A silly doubt on Log structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ be an affine variety. Consider the log structure given by $\mathbb N\rightarrow A$ which sends $1\mapsto 0$. Also consider the log structure $\mathbb N^r \rightarrow A$ given by $e_i\rightarrow 0$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$ and $e_i$ denotes the basis of $\mathbb N^r$. Are these two log structures non-isomorphic?

My doubt is that these two log structure are basically not different.

Comment: Consider $A = k$ a field. The log structure associated to the map $P\to k$ for a sharp monoid $P$ sending $0\mapsto 1$ and everything else to $0$ is $\mathcal{M} = P\times k^* \to k$ mapping $(0, a) \mapsto a$ and everything else to $0$. It follows that $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{O}^\times \simeq P$. In particular, different $P$'s give rise to non-isomorphic log schemes.